# Can't execute a project, problems with the COM component

Tags: c#, .net, com

I'm trying to execute a program, which i have just downloaded from Subversion, and it is working fine on another computer, but on my computer, it just doesn't run. 
It doesn't shows any error, and it is only a warning.

> Cannot find wrapper assembly for type library "VBIDE". Verify that (1)
>   the COM component is registered correctly and (2) your target platform
>   is the same as the bitness of the COM component. For example, if the
>   COM component is 32-bit, your target platform must not be 64-bit.

So my questions are: 
How can i know if the COM component is registered correctly? 
How can i know the bitness of the COM component?

Comment: When you get this warning then you *know* that the COM component is not registered on your machine.  The name for it in the COM tab of the Add Reference dialog is "Microsoft Visual Basic for Application Extensibility", it is normally installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB.  Perhaps you don't have Office installed on your machine if it is missing.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I've done that, and installed .NET Framework 4.5.2 [link] (http://dotnetsocial.cloudapp.net/GetDotnet?tfm=.NETFramework,Version=v4.5,Profile=Client&processName=MEMAltaW7.vshost.exe&platform=0009&osver=5&isServer=0) , and now it is working.

Comment: Ok, it WAS working, suddenly i had the same problem again

Answer (score 2):

> Just follow the below steps:

```
View => Solution Explorer => Expand References Tab => Delete VBIDE reference by Right Click => Rebuild or Debug your Solution
```

> You must be ready to go!!!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following link. Hope this might help.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809975.aspx

http://devblog.com.au/cannot-find-wrapper-assembly-for-type-library-vbide

Comment: I have read that, but none of the tips there had helped me. Any of my references seems to have troubles now, but still the project just don't execute on my computer.

Comment: Well, now I went to Project properties > Application, choose Target Framework: .NET Framework 4 and deselect "Enable application framework", and it seems to be working.